# How can GrandChil Component in blazor call a ParentComponent Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

Note: I am a new to this.

In Parent I have a method that adds a product to an order.
In my child I have a foreach for the grandchild component
In granchild I have a productcard with a button.

I am trying to @onclick call the parent method to add that specific product to the order. But it doesn't work.

Eventcallback only seems to be able to call a the child method.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Cascade the method.  something like this:  `[CascadingParameter] public Action<Product>? AddProduct { get; set; }` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Answer (score 0):

You chould use `<CascadingValue Value="this">` to pass everything (including method) to grandchild. Try follwoing sample:
Parent.razor

```
@page "/parent"
<h3>Parent</h3>
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    <Child />
</CascadingValue>
@code {

    public void Add(string product)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(product+" Added");
    }
}
```

Child.razor

```
<GrandChild />
```

GrandChild.razor

```
@page "/parent"
<h3>Parent</h3>
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    <Child />
</CascadingValue>
@code {

    public void Add(string product)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(product+" Added");
    }
}
```

Test result
[image]